# Titles and axis legends in dyplot.prophet graphing function

Tags: r

I have just started to use Facebook's Prophet library in R, I have a question regarding the dyplot.prophet graphing function.  I have created a plot using this code:

```
dyplot.prophet(m,forecast,uncertainty=TRUE)
```

This works fine, but the resulting graph has no x or y axis labels or a main title, I would like to add some to the plot.

The documentation describes the following

```
dyplot.prophet(x, fcst, uncertainty = TRUE, ...)
```

Where: 
**x** is the Prophet object, 
**fcast**  is the data frame returned by predict(m, df), and 
**uncertainty** is the Boolean indicating if the uncertainty interval for yhat is to be plotted.  There are then **…** indicating additional arguments, I would like to know what these arguments are, and if any of them relate to plot titles or axis legends.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! Please go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812).

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to add titles.

dyplot.prophet(m,forecast,main="Graph")

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!